# how to use devexpress checkbox like radiobutton realtime in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

i have 2 checkboxes html with devexpress.
i want to use this devexpress checkboxes like radiobutton in realtime.

so when user click one checkbox, another checkboxes will be unchecked.

```
    <div>
         @Html.DevExpress().CheckBoxFor(x => x.CBComplete, settings =>
         {
             settings.Text = "Complete";
         }).GetHtml()
   </div>
   <div>
         @Html.DevExpress().CheckBoxFor(x => x.CBPartial, settings =>
         {
             settings.Text = "Partial";
         }).GetHtml()
   </div>
```

I also try this javascript method but not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#CBComplete").change(
        function (e) {
            debugger;
            $("#CBPartial").attr('checked',!this.checked);
      }
    );
    debugger;
    $("#CBPartial").change(
        function (e) {
            debugger;
            $("#CBComplete").attr('checked',!this.checked);
      }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a group of RadioButtons of even RadioButtonList instead:

https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDataEditorsDemos/Editors/RadioButtonList

https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-use-the-checkboxlist-and-radiobuttonlist-editors-to-edit-model-fields-e4125

Comment: in demo of devexpress use radiobuttonlist, if i use radiobuttonfor how to group them to 1, to make it select-unselect

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve that, you should use checkbox style in radiobutton.